# Google Sheets custom formula in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to add a custom formula to a cell range if its text value is exactly as a text in a specific cell.

This is my formula:

```
"=EXACT(B9,'חישובים לסיכום'!B13)"
```

and this is my screen shot:

[image]

Although the texts are the same, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google spreadsheets custom formulas won't reference other sheets directly, but the workaround is to use INDIRECT, which takes a cell reference as a string, so try this:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheetname!B13")=B9
```